# chart representation in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a table in sql server database.
How can i represent this data as charts using wpf and c#

Comment: What kind of chart?  What kind of data?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to build your own, I think your best bet is to get a 3rd party charting library. there are commercial ones--[telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) for example-- and there are some free/opensource out there, like [VisiFire](http://www.visifire.com/).

Comment: VisiFire is not free.  Not even close.

Comment: @A.R. they USED to have an opensource option.  They must have changed since the last time I checked them out.

Comment: versions of Visifire previous to 4 are still opensource and free to use http://www.visifire.com/blog/2011/02/08/license-changes/

Answer (score 1):

Check [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) for a set of cool [FREE] chart controls

[This page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/06/25/wpf-charting-it-s-official-june-2009-release-of-the-wpf-toolkit-is-now-available.aspx) contains an example that you can download. and [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WPFCharting11272009153918PM/WPFCharting.aspx) is another (more detailed) example.

Hope this helps :)